# Is there really a way to save history of visited sites so that when user comes back(reopens app) he has the list of visited sites on back press

Tags: java, android, kotlin, browser-history

I am just making a simple browser with history management.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could look to an open source project like the Zirco Browser -> https://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/

Some code like this > https://code.google.com/p/zirco-browser/source/browse/branches/tint-browser-old2/src/org/tint/controllers/BookmarksHistoryController.java

```
   /**
         * Get a Cursor the history, e.g. records wich have a visits count > 0. Sorted by last visited date.
         * @param currentActivity The parent activity.
         * @return A Cursor to history records.
         * @see Cursor
         */
        public Cursor getHistory(Activity currentActivity) {
                String whereClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS + " > 0";
                String orderClause = Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC";

                return currentActivity.managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, whereClause, null, orderClause);
        }
```

Perhaps you could copy some code and use it for your project.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a doubly-linked LinkedList to maintain a history, but WebView already contains methods to deal with forward and back history.

```
void     goBack()
```

> Goes back in the history of this WebView.

```
void     goBackOrForward(int steps)
```

> Goes to the history item that is the number of steps away from the
>   current item.

```
void     goForward()
```

> Goes forward in the history of this WebView.

From the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 1):

```
// put this in your xml file...

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

// then in your code

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
{
    // Links clicked will be shown on the webview
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}

// Then to load the webpage from edit text would be
webView.loadUrl(--Edit Text URL here);

// To go back to your previous page, call this method
webView.goBack();

// To go to your next page would be
webView.goForward();
```